# HTML5 Form verification blocks the password to 16 chars, how to change?

Tags: html, forms

I did a simple login form, but a customer wants to input a password with 24 characters. Strangely enough, it seems that the form validator from HTML5 is blocking it at 16 which is really annoying. I tried pattern but didn't work. Any ideas?

```
<input type="password" id="password" name="password" pattern=".{5,25}" required />
```

**So I want to limit it to 24 characters instead of default 16.**

[image]

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add `maxlength="24"` to your attributes

ie

```
<input type="password" id="password" name="password" maxlength="24" required="true" />
```